# Problems publishing C# project with external serialized object file and lucene DB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, lucene.net, publish

I am finally at the alpha phase of my project and I am ready to publish.

I perform the publish routine from VS2012 express and it generates the folder with the files along with the installer. Before the process completes I get an error that it cannot find user.dat file which is binary file where I serialize some objects.

My intention is to have both this file along with the lucene DB files located on a network drive and just have the working directory or a file path extension pointing to that. I do not want either of these files included in the install package.

How do I split them out?

When coding this up I had both in the home directory of the project and I was just going to switch the file path to the actual location.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the user.dat file is included in your solution/project and configured to be deployed.